# Trying to make sure my system is updated properly. Ubuntu20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I ran the command `sudo apt-get install update` and as you can see my results below:

```
cyberwizard34@Hogwarts:~$ sudo apt-get install update
[sudo] password for cyberwizard34: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa uses - like its ancestors - [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt.8.html)

Before you can upgrade your running system you need to update the package-cache for the repositories that are enabled on your system, by using:

```
sudo apt update
```

Once that is done, you have to upgrade - meaning applying the newly found patches to your system, by using:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This should be it, except if you are using packages that are not supported anymore and/or you made manual changes to packages that were regularly installed via apt from your current repositories/sources; In that case, you would have to use:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

The difference to `sudo apt full-upgrade` is that `sudo apt upgrade` does not remove packages from your system; which would be done for example because those non-standard packages reached end-of-life, were replaced by another (meta-) package or do break the dependency chain, which you might have willfully ignored.

If you are new to Ubuntu, Distros based on Debian (using apt as a package manager) or in general to GNU/Linux Distributions, you can ignore the alternative method, namely `sudo apt upgrade`, just use the first two commands mentioned:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

[ The `&&` just chains commands, so you can write/copy-paste this one-liner.]